# How to read Logs from external firewall

Tags: c#, java, networking, network-programming, firewall

I want to read external firewall logs with java or c# programming language, but I don't know where to start. The purpose is to learn which user surfs, which websites in the internet.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing what firewall you're talking about. If you know which firewall it is, look up its documentation to find out whether it's possible to read the data you want.

Comment: 1) Option A: Check if the FW provider lists an API, WS to do so. 2) Option B: Think that you would do "manually" and try to repeat it with a program.

Answer (score 0):

just send syslogs from your fw to a syslog server and go through the logs with a script in whatever language...
you can easily analyze what and how many clients are connecting to which server ip address which you can map to services then.

br,

Comment: The application must do its job programmatically. I must take into account about writing the application for which firewall as CodeCaster said.